# Convert String to Json type in python with socket programming

Tags: python, json, multithreading, sockets

```
data = data.decode('utf-8')
print(data)   # b'1' : {"reciever": "1", "sender:": 1, "seq_num": 7, "data": "2"}
data = data[7:] 
print(data)   # {"reciever": "1", "sender:": 1, "seq_num": 7, "data": "2"}
data = json.dumps(data)
data = json.loads(data)
print(type(data)) #<class 'str'>
```

Here is my code. I try to send data (string + json) with socket programming.
It sends data well, but I want to use json when receiving messages.
So I sliced the json part, and dumps and loads into json. (I imported json)
But Its type is still in str.

In my sending function,

```
result = json.dumps({'reciever' : rec, 'sender:': sender, 'seq_num' : sequence_number, 'data': data})
final_result = json.loads(result)
print(type(final_result)). #dict type
```

It seems works well here.

Please help !

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `data = json.dumps(data)`.

`json.dumps` saves `json object` to `str`. but `data` is already `str` in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much !